# How to populate web form using Selenium and Google Chrome with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome, webforms

I am trying to populate a web form and click "submit" using Selenium with Excel VBA.

I have VBA code for opening the website.

I need to add to the VBA code to;

1. Insert the text from sheet rawdata (cell B1) into the webpage box named "subject"
2. Insert the text from sheet rawdata (cell C1) into the webpage box named "messagetext"
3. Click on button (type = "submit") value="Send message" in the webpage.

VBA code which opens the webpage in a Chrome browser.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub openurl()

Dim ChromeLocation As String
Dim MyURL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Range("A1").Select

lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Set ws1 = Sheets("rawdata")

ChromeLocation = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" 'Location of 
Chrome.exe in your PC

For i = 1 To lastRow

    MyURL = ws1.Cells(i, 1)

    Shell (ChromeLocation & " -url -newtab " & MyURL)


    'I want to insert code here to be able to
    ' enter text from cell B1 in sheet "rawdata" and
    ' enter it in to the subject box on the web page
 
    'I want to insert code here to be able to
    ' enter text from cell C1 in sheet "rawdata" and
    ' enter it in to the messagetext box on the web page

    'I want to insert code here to be able to
    ' click on the button "Sendmessage" to submit the form.

Next i

End Sub
```

HTML from the website with the relevant lines of code for "subject", "messagetext" and the Submit button.

```
" Subject: "
<input type="text" name="subject" value="">
<p></p>


<textarea style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13pt; color: 
black; width: 90%; max-width: 600px" rows="10" cols="50" name="messagetext"></textarea>
<p></p>


<input type="submit" value="Send message">
```

Comment: I would have solved this by exporting the rawdata tab to a textfile from VBA. Then I'd read that file into python and populate and submit the form for each row of data there.

Comment: What is an example of a URL from ws1.Cells(i, 1) ?

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your message.   The urls won’t be constant and need to change for every row in the spreadsheet “raw data”.  Can python be used to load data to multiple urls in the same bit of code?

Comment: While Python would certainly work for this, it can also be achieved with VBA relatively easily. I recommend [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/FoxWcvZzYVk) including the follow up videos.

Comment: I will have a look at that.   The problem I’ve had is that chrome opens and immediately closes, unless websites are accessed using the shell function. 

And that’s where I’m struggling, to find videos / websites where a web form has been called using shell and then entering the data in the form on the webpage.

Comment: @Mark Yes, python "be used to load data to multiple urls in the same bit of code."

Comment: I’ve watched that video (and many others) already GWD and it didn’t help with what I am trying to achieve 

If I was using IE and the website used ID tags it would be easy for me to do.  

But the website doesn’t use ID as tags and I have s to open chrome using shell.  It’s the code to populate a field on the web form and then click submit I am totally stuck with. 

Thank you